# preg_replace PHP AND

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Is there a `AND` operator for PHP - regular expression.

I'm trying to replace everything from `document` to `'` AND `)`.

```
$output = preg_replace('/document.*\'/', '', $output);
```

Any idea how this can be done?

I've tried to find some tutorial for RegEX but I can't find any good. If you have any good sites or book please give me a link. I googled a lot.

Thanks.

EDIT: Misunderstanding.

This is the code before replaced.

```
<p>document.write(unescape('
<embed src="XXXXXX" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="window" width="712" height="475"%.35" allowFullScreen="true" ></embed>
')));</p>
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
<p>
<embed src="XXXXXX" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="window" width="712" height="475"%.35" allowFullScreen="true" ></embed>
</p>
```

Replaced:

```
document.write(unescape('
```

and

```
')));
```

Comment: Most frequently http://regular-expressions.info/ is recommended. The introductions are mostly understandable. Also look into this tools list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for help with crafting regexpressions.

Comment: Creds for using delimiters. So many newcomers do not. :)

Comment: @mario I checked it before. It didnt look newcomer -friendly. I'll take a look again, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want is to replace two parts, and leave something in between over. To not make it match undesired parts, use explicit character classes:

```
= preg_replace("/document[\w.(]+['](.*?)['][);]+/s", '$1', $output);
```

So it matches anything enclosed in `('` and `')` with varying amounts of the latter.

Comment: The code does not replace anything or give any errors. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Muazam: True. Try again with the `/s` modifier. Works on your example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `OR`?

You want to strip ranges `["document", "'"]` and ranges `["document", ")"]`, right? Which is like the range `["document", "'" OR ")"]`.

In regular expressions, `|` means "or".

```
$output = preg_replace('/document.*(\'|\))/', '', $output);
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, updated first post with an example.

Comment: @Muazam: I still don't really get it. Maybe I'm just too tired.

Comment: @Muazam: Your question didn't ask me to :(

Answer (score 0):

In regular expression, AB is `A and B` A|B is `A OR B`

So if you want to match `')` then just put that in the regular expression.

On the other hand if you want to match either `'` or `)` as the end of your string use `'|)` or `[')]`

Use something like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to try out your regexes. It also has descriptions on the right.

Comment: I want to match them both, but not in order. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Use parenthesis to create matching group
- Use $1 to refer to it

`$output = preg_replace("/document[^']*'([^']*)[^;]*;/", '$1', $output);`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ']', That looks like some advance RegEX. Thanks for helping :)